# creation of function handle in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
N= input('nodes');
e5= ones(N,1);
e4= ones((N-1),1);
A = -2*diag(e5)+diag(e4,1)+diag(e4,-1)
k = sym('k',[N 1])
s = A*k;
f = (A*k)-(sign(k).*((k).^2))
g = diff(f,k)
```

> 

The problem is that the code seen above creates a function with the set of input arguments (k1,k2) instead of (k). and also not running differentiation command.

Comment: problem in diff(f) also

Answer (score 2):

Use `f=@(k)`:

```
f = @(k)A*k-sign(k).*k.^2
f([3; 2])
```

To differentiate, first use `sym(f)`. Treating `k` as a scalar:

```
diff(sym(f))
```

which gives, in this case

```
[ - 2*k*sign(k) - 2*k^2*dirac(k) - 2,   1 - 2*k^2*dirac(k) - 2*k*sign(k)]
[   1 - 2*k^2*dirac(k) - 2*k*sign(k), - 2*k*sign(k) - 2*k^2*dirac(k) - 2]
```

But I don't think that is what you want. Perhaps you are looking for `diff(sym(f([k1;k2])),k1)` and `diff(sym(f([k1;k2])),k2)`?

Comment: If you give the answer you want, I'll try to give the Matlab to get it. If you want to treat `k` as a vector you probably want to consider components, no?